# Problems in transmitting a List<> Object over a socket

Tags: java, list, sockets

I dont know why but suddenly i am facing problems in sending and receiving a List over a TCP socket, initially I was successful in doing so. Here is my transfer code:
Sender:

```
List<String> A = ....;
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
System.out.println("Wrinting the answers");
out.writeObject(A);
System.out.println("Wrote the answers, now reading the flag");
```

I am getting the SOP correctly, however the reciever goes into waiting state:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());             
ls = (List<String>)in.readObject();
System.out.println("Recieved the list of results");
```

Here I am not getting the SOP and the receiver continues to be in waiting state. 
To add: I was successful in transfering the List previously, but then I made a few changes here and there and now dont know what is the problem. I actually intend to transfer another List<> too, but I will try that only when I get the solution to the first problem! Thanks for your answer..

Comment: try to convert list object to Object type and send

Comment: A list *is* an Object. There's nothing to convert.

Comment: You have the SOP working fine, because the data you write is buffered. You should call `out.flush()` once you are done writing object(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
System.out.println("Wrinting the answers");
out.writeObject(A);
out.flush();  // flush the stream!
System.out.println("Wrote the answers, now reading the flag");
```

Comment: i had tried to flush, still not i am getting the same result.